# Как убрать плюсы из get параметров?

Tags: javascript

Такая вот история приключилась. Некий недосервис присылает webhook пост параметром в котором лежит массив. Все это приходит в google script, где подобные штуки не катят и надо писать парсер URL что бы вытянуть данные из многомерного массива который прилетел постом. Это я сделал, все разобрал. Появилась проблема такова что пробелы в ссылках заменяются знаком +. Вопрос таков как заменить + на пробел и не затронуть плюсы которые должны находится в тексте.

Comment: Может поможет encodeURIComponent()

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: DemoS, Не знаю почему но не помогло(

Comment: @makcim512 странно конечно, посмотрите что выводит консоль при обработке этой функцией ссылки. Ну как вариант попробуйте вручную пробелы заменить на %20

Comment: @DemoS если + заменить на  %20 то все работает, вот только проблема в том что приходят с + а не с %20

Comment: @makcim512 вы пишете "Появилась проблема такова что пробелы в ссылках заменяются знаком +". В какой момент то они такими становятся? Значит нужно кодировать до этого. А вообще показали бы пример ссылки, какой у вас результат, какой результат хотите получить

Comment: @DemoS Вот так приходит fields[1][value][]=первое+второе+третьеСлово  надо вот так fields[1][value][]=первое второе третьеСлово . Перечитайте вопрос, ссылка приходит с + а нужно убрать эти + поскольку в место них должны стоять пробелы.

Comment: @makcim512 ну раз приходит уже с + вместо пробела, то я думаю что нет возможности отличить плюс в тексте от плюса который вместо пробела. Потому только замена всех +

Comment: @DemoS есть возможность. Читайте мой ответ)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если кому то понадобится, то вот ответ:

```
decodeURIComponent(url.replace(/\+/g,  " "))
```

Не знаю каким образом JS определяет + но это работает).

> **Для особо умных!** Плюсы в тексте не заменяются. Я провел много тестов, не 1 плюс в тексте не пострадал.

Comment: Вы так заменяете все + на пробел, даже если они будут в тексте. Хотя в вопросе написали "...не затронуть плюсы которые должны находится в тексте".

Comment: @DemoS Плюсы в тексте не заменяются, уже проверил! Все работает нормально!